# How to cache internal service calls with Servicestack

Tags: servicestack

Should it be possible to cache server responses to services calls done via Gateway.Send() from within another service?

I've seen you comments stating that if I enable caching with [CacheResponse] attribute it should work.

However, it isn't caching the response for me. I'm using ServiceStack v5.1.0

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack caching features only caches HTTP Requests which are serialized in the registered [Cache provider](http://docs.servicestack.net/caching) and written directly to the Response Output Stream.

In Process [Service Gateway](http://docs.servicestack.net/service-gateway) requests are never serialized, cached or written to a Stream, they're effectively an in-process C# method call when calling an internal Service, if the gateway request is routed to a remote Service that's cached it will return the cached response as per normal HTTP request.

Otherwise if you want to cache an In Memory Service Gateway request you can use a ConcurrentDictionary in your Service implementation and memoize results as you would when caching any expensive C# logic.

Comment: I'd ideally like to cache these calls so that they would match cache keys for when they are also called directly from HttpClient. (We've code running both server and client side hitting the same services).

Comment: @richardwhatever You wouldn't be sharing the same cache, external HTTP Requests are serialized whereas you should just be caching the response DTO for internal requests (avoiding any de/serialization). FYI you can use `base.Request.IsInProcessRequest()` to determine if it's an internal Service Gateway request.

Comment: To check my understanding, you're saying that for internal service response caching I should write my own and ignore all the ServiceStack APIs like ICacheClient, and ToOptimizedResultUsingCache.

The principle behind this advice is that ICacheClient relies on caching serialised objects and the inefficiency of serialising them outweighs the convenience of using them. And/or Gateway.Send when used in process doesn't enable automatic serialisation into the caching api via a call of ToOptimizedResultUsingCache.

Comment: Therefore in process response caching should really only ever be a transient, in-memory cache.

Am I getting this right?

Many thanks.

Comment: ServiceStack caches and returns the most optimal output for HTTP Requests, i.e. it will cache and write the cached compressed (if client supports it) serialized response directly to the Response OutputStream. But you don't want to De/Serialize + Stream in-process requests, if you do want to cache expensive C# logic use a ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: I'm wanting to cache service responses for use when when internally calling services from controllers. I am planning to use LazyCache as it provides a simple solution, however, i'm unclear if its a better approach than using service.LocalCache?  Is LocalCache also only suitable for caching HTTP requests?

Comment: @richardwhatever Not sure what LazyCache is, but the ICacheClient APIs have  GetOrCreate/Async APIs for that pattern. For local objects I'd only use MemoryCacheClient if an entry needed to expire or if sometime in the future it may need to be stored in a distributed cache, otherwise for permanent in memory object caches I'd just use a ConcurentDictionary.

Comment: Is there much overhead for using MemoryCacheClient vs ConcurrentDictionary?

Comment: @richardwhatever Relative to what? I/O no, micro benchmarks, yes any overhead would show a difference. It's just a [fairly simple wrapper over a ConcurrentDictionary](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Caching/MemoryCacheClient.cs) which stores the entry in a simple metadata class to maintain its expiration. When you retrieve it just checks to see if it's expired, which is why I've said if you don't need that feature or future compatibility with ICacheClient use a ConcurrentDictionary directly instead.